# Are there any advantage of using multiple threads for a file upload, for an internet connected node?

Tags: internet, protocol-theory, network-access

I got asked in an intervew recently to design a file upload feature.
After initial discussion, The interviewer asked if I can design for multiple threads. My thought was, As the network bandwidth is limited and the internet is connected through a serial data connection, the network bottleneck will kick-in much before the CPU bottleneck, and a multiple thread implementation would have a limited performance improvement.
But the interviewer was hell bend on the multi-thread approach.
What are the arguments in favor of a multi-thread upload approach.
*(I recently came to know that AWS has a library which permits uploads on mutliple threads. So there should be some advantages I am unaware of.)*

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. This sounds more like a question for [so].

Comment: As unfortunate as it can get, I thought about it initially and avoided posting it on SO thinking of a moderation onslaught! I just posted it there now! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

With **TCP** the advantage starts if you can fill multiple windows.

With **UDP** the advantage is if your systems are ever waiting on turnaround time.

There are also network performance improvements if there is a bandwidth limit per host-port association at any part of the link, though that might well be considered as subverting a policy by those who put the limit in.